# Конвертировать текст на русском из pdf в txt python

Tags: python, pdf

Пытаюсь конвертировать кирилицу из pdf в txt c помощью *PyPDF2* в *Python*:

```
import PyPDF2
pdf_file = open('mail_cir.pdf', 'rb')
read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
number_of_pages = read_pdf.getNumPages()
page = read_pdf.getPage(0)
page_content = page.extractText()
print (page_content.encode('utf-8'))
```

Ошибки не выдает, но и текст не видит.

Пыталась изменить:

```
 pdf_file = codecs.open('mail_cir.pdf', 'rb', encoding='utf-8')
```

Тогда выдается ошибка:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly

И другой вопрос:

Если конвертировать стих, то после окончания строки на пустом месте выводится `\n \n`. Как избавиться от этих символов?

Comment: Вы уверены что PDF имеет текст? Он может быть просто изображением страницы показывает.

Comment: Безусловно PDF имеет текст. Проверяю- вставляю в текст на кирилице текст на латинском алфавите- текст выводится, на русском нет. Спасибо за ответ .

Comment: `print (page_content.decode('cp1251').encode('utf-8'))` попробуйте, я давно с python не работал, и сейчас нет возможности проверить, может поможет

Comment: Выдает ошибку :`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Comment: @A1essandro, тестировал этой же библиотекой и `extractText` вернул текст, но только ascii, кириллица в нем отсутствовала

Comment: @gil9red, получается при помощи PyPDF2 вообще нельзя конвертировать кирилицу. Может кто то знает какой библиотекой можно?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться [PDFMiner](https://github.com/goulu/pdfminer), чтобы текст, включающий русские буквы, из pdf достать:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pdfminer.high_level # $ pip install pdfminer.six

with open('mail_cir.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(file, sys.stdout)
```

[`pdf2txt.py` показывает как эта функция может быть использована](https://github.com/goulu/pdfminer/blob/master/tools/pdf2txt.py)—можно много опций передать.

#### Ввод (в pdf)

```
English 
На русском 
Smiley: ☺
non-BMP smiley:
```

#### Вывод (текст в консоли)

```
English На русском Smiley: ☺non-BMP smiley:
```

Русский текст нормально извлёкся, но non-BMP смайлик  (U+1F602) и флаги  (U+1F1EC U+1F1E7),  (U+1F1F7 U+1F1FA) потерялись при конвертации.

---

Код с `PyPDF2`, похожий на приведённый в вопросе, смог извлечь только символы в ASCII диапазоне.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ !!! Но у меня возникает проблема:    `from pdftypes import PDFObjectNotFound  ImportError: cannot import name 'PDFObjectNotFound`

Comment: @Olga: если у вас сложности с установкой `pdfminer.six` пакета. То задайте отдельный вопрос специально об установке именно этого пакета. Укажите явно какой командой устанавливали? (`pip install pdfminer.six`). Какая ОСь? Версия Питона? `pdfminer.__version__`? Добавьте минимальный пример кода, который к `ImportError` приводит (часть кода, приведённого в ответе выше)  и полный traceback. Код в ответе я запускал—вы не должны получить ImportError.

Comment: Вопрос решен ! Спасибо огромное !!!