# Возможно ли с помощью Python загрузить/применить файл шрифта(.ttf/.otf) в документ .doc/.docx/pdf?

Tags: python, шрифты, pdf, docx

Ознакомился с документацией библиотеки python-docx,в ней есть возможность оперировать установленными в системе шрифтами, нашёл библиотеку FontTools, которая позволяет конвертировать файлы шрифтов в xml-формат. 
Но нигде не нашёл информации по поводу того возможно ли загрузить, каким либо образом, файл шрифта(в формате .ttf/.otf.) в документ(word: doc/docx, либо pdf).
Обязательно ли, сначала, установить шрифт в систему?
Буду рад любой информации/подсказкам/наводкам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, не обязательно в систему ставить. Можно шрифт внутрь документа добавить (embed):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from fpdf import FPDF  # $ pip install fpdf

output_filename = 'unicode.pdf'
# http://unifoundry.com/pub/unifont-10.0.05/font-builds/unifont-10.0.05.ttf
font_path = 'unifont-10.0.05.ttf'

# https://helloworldcollection.github.io/#Human
# NOTE: what characters are supported depends on the font
text = u"""
Afrikaans Hallo, wêreld!
Albanian Pershëndetje Botë
Arabic أهلاً بالعالم (Ahlan bil 'Alam)
Armenian Բարե՛ւ, աշխարհ։ (barev ash'kharh)
Azeri Salam Dünya
...
"""

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
# http://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Unicode/
# add unicode font (otherwise only latin-1 is supported)
font_family = 'family'
pdf.add_font(family=font_family, fname=font_path, uni=True)
pdf.set_font(family=font_family, size=12)
pdf.write(h=5, txt=text)
pdf.output(output_filename)
```

Comment: хорошее решение, но я так понимаю, что fpdf - формирует документ, т.е. в существующий pdf-файл, через данную библиотеку нельзя загрузить шрифт, это так?

Comment: @leexxg fpdf только пишет. Если хотите прочитать текст из pdf, [можно pdfminer использовать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/591455/23044).

Answer (score 1):

Да, шрифт обязательно должен быть установлен в системе.
Перед сохранением документа в пдф - в фотошопе/кореле/другом редакторе переведите шрифты в кривые или растрируйте. Текст нельзя будет при этом редактировать. 
Либо передавайте с документом файл шрифта

Comment: да, устанавливать, как оказалось обязательно, но есть ли какое-либо решение на python,хотя бы с установкой?