# Парсинг текста из PDF файла, расположенном на сайте

Tags: python, парсер, pdf

Есть пдф файл, расположенный на сайте колледжа.
 Хочу вытащить из него информацию, допустим, по группе МЧМ 17-2 с помощью пайтона. Каким путем лучше это сделать? На ум приходит только это:
     1)скачать файл, переконвертировать в TXT и парсить из него(не уверен что лучший способ,т.к. в PDF таблица)
     2)не скачивая файл с помощью парсера "скопировать" информацию ? 
[image: пример PDF]

Comment: не скачивая, "скопировать" информацию нельзя. Можно на диск не сохранять и/или на лету информацию вытаскивать (если формат файла позволяет), но скачивать придётся.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Конвертировать текст на русском из pdf в txt python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/588894/23044)