# PyPDF2 не читает символы. Python, PDF, pdfminer

Tags: python, кодировка, pdf, работа-с-текстом

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Хочу прочитать PDF файл с помощью PyPDF, чтобы одна конкретная страница сохранялась в .тхт файл

Код:

```
import PyPDF2 
pl = open('111.pdf', 'rb') #открываю файл в режиме чтения по битам
plread = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pl) 
getpage2 = plread.getPage(2) #определенная страница
text2 = getpage2.extractText() #
print(text2.encode('utf-8')) #принт в командною строку в ютф-8
with open('bdseoru_pdf.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fg:
    fg.write(text2) #запись в файл .тхт
```

выполняю запуск в командной строке, получаю вот такой результат:

```
A:\py\projects3\morningBot>python t.py
b'\n \n\n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n \n\n(\n1647\n) \n \n\n \n\n \n\n-\n \n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n-\n \n\n \n\n\n\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n:\n \n\n \n\n-\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n \n\n\n \n \n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n \n\n\n \n\n \n\n\n \n\n\n\n. \n \n\n\n\n \n\n\n \n\n\n? \n \n\n \n\n \n\n\n\n \n\n \n\n\n \n\n \n\n\n\n\n\n \n \n'
```

в сохраненном файле.тхт похожий результат, только вместо "\n" переносы строки, что логично.
Но никаких букв нет.
Пробовал убирать кодировку:

```
.encode('utf-8')
```

без этого лучше не становится,
пробовал менять на "ascii" и "unicode", тоже не работает.

*уже не знаю, какие костыли приделать, я думал переформатировать .pdf в .doc и обработать там, но с .doc или .docx работать еще геморнее, не нашел нормальной библиотеки, которая могла бы постранично читать. Этому тоже буду рад, если подскажет кто-то...*

*Говорят воспользоваться **pdfminer**, но я не нашел документации, которая мне помогла бы сделать то же самое. Еще говорят, что PyPDF2 ПЛОХО работает с кириллицей, но если хоть как-то работает, то что-то же должно быть!? нет?*

Если есть инфа как в pdfminer сделать такой же код - буду рад подсказкам...

---

**UPD:**

---

Нашел ответ в [похожем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/588894/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-pdf-%D0%B2-txt-python)

Сработал код:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import pdfminer.high_level # $ pip install pdfminer.six

with open('111.pdf', 'rb') as file:
    pdfminer.high_level.extract_text_to_fp(file, sys.stdout)
```

Получалось открыть в командной строке текст.
Но при попытке сохранить его, или выделить отдельную страницу терпел поражение.

Может можно как-то совместить PyPDF & pdfminer, чтобы один открывал, а другой сохранял и выбирал страницу?

Comment: В документации библиотеки как-то хитро про эту функцию написано вообще: "This works well for some PDF files, but poorly for others, depending on the generator used." Типа, может работать, а может и не работать.

Comment: Так там в ответе, на который вы ссылаетесь, есть ссылка на [pdf2txt.py](https://github.com/goulu/pdfminer/blob/master/tools/pdf2txt.py). В котором можно подсмотреть необходимые опции.